# Semantic Mediawiki forms

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I am using [Semantic Mediawiki Form](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms). I want to change the URL and I'd like to structure the URL so that it contains some fields. E.g.: `{country}/{state}/{city}`.

I want to add these three details to the URL. How do I add that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but do you want to preload your form with some data from the url? In that case it depends on what forms you are talking about. SF comes with forms for editing and forms for making queries.

*Query forms can be preloaded with data from the url (though the recommended way is through a special parser function), see http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms/Linking_to_forms

*In editing forms you can only use predefined templates, like this: `{{#forminput:form=MyForm|query string=preload=Template:MyPreloadTemplate}}`